# autolayout constraint was changed back after I set a value to it

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a view and a property as the height constraint.

I will change the constraint value at run time, code like:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear {
[super viewWillAppear];
if (list.count) {
        self.FilterBarViewHeightConstraint.constant = 35;
        [self.ChartContainerView layoutIfNeeded];
        // do something..
} else {
        self.FilterBarViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
        [self.ChartContainerView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

I debug the single step, that the constant was set to 0, but when view are drawing on the screen, I found the constraint was changed back to 35. I am wondering, how can I debug this kind of issue, and why it is changed?

If I capture a view hierarchy, Xcode did show me the self.height auto layout is 35. But I do changed it:

Before,

```
(lldb) po self.FilterBarViewHeightConstraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffae9f5b300 V:[UIView:0x7ffae9fec800(35)]>
```

After calling self.FilterBarViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0;

```
(lldb) po self.FilterBarViewHeightConstraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffae9f5b300 V:[UIView:0x7ffae9fec800(0)]>
```

After view fully displayed, and capture the view hierarchy again:

```
(lldb) po 0x7ffae9f5b300
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffae9f5b300 V:[UIView:0x7ffae9fec800(35)]>
```

Comment: What happens when you place the code in viewDidAppear?  Also, it is good practice to call viewWillAppear on the parent class as well (i.e. `[super viewWillAppear:animated];`)

Comment: Do you get any messages about conflicting constraints?

Comment: NO, I don't get any conflict log. I have been used this kind of way to solve similar situations, but none of them has such problem. The idea is to use this height constraint to decide whether the view should occupy some space. The view below it has top margin as 0, so if the view height constraint is set to 0, below views will take the space up.

Comment: @JoshGafni, I have code that do the super stuff. Forgot to add here

Comment: I am looking for some guidance or debugging skills that how the auto layout process in iOS, I feel some where changed it back. But I am not familiar with the whole process, so Have no idea where to start debugging.

Comment: Figured out if I put the updating constraint code in main queue, it works! But question comes, why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code in main queue solved my issue. But still need more knowledge on this.

```
else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.FilterBarViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
            [self.ChartContainerView layoutIfNeeded];
        });}
```